# Disabling Fullscreen also disables Night light [Problem]

Tags: nvidia, window, minecraft, fullscreen

When I'm playing videogames (for example Minecraft), whenever I turn on Fullscreen mode and then I turn it off (so going to Windowed mode) it disables Night light for some reason.

If I then go to settings I can see that Night light is ON, but it's actually OFF (The settings says it's on, but I can see that it's disabled). And to turn on night light again, I have to toggle twice the night light setting (Turning OFF the night light, and then turning it ON again)

I'm currently using X11 instead of Wayland, I tried to change it to Wayland but it the issue persists.

I tried to update my graphic card's drivers to the latest (My GPU is 1660 SUPER)

I tried to update my bios

But nothing works.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
GNOME Version 42.5
My CPU is AMD Ryzen 5 3600.
My GPU is NVIDIA GTX 1660 SUPER.
I have 2 monitors. One is at 240hz and the other at 60hz (maybe this is the issue? I tried to unplug the second monitor but it doesn't work either)

Does anyone have any idea to solve this issue?